# Replace value of array based on if condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array which I am using some method to make an api call. I have 2 methods out of which I need to select 1 based on the session value.

My array looks like this.

```
$order_params = array(
  'username' => 'test1',
  'password' => 'test2',
  'method' => 'Gateway1');
```

So if session value is not null than method needs to be Gateway2 and need to pass one more parameter. What I am doing is using this way to update the array.

```
$order_params = array(
  'username' => 'test1',
  'password' => 'test2',
  'method' => 'Gateway1');

if($_SESSION['userid'] != ''){
    $order_params['method'] = 'Gateway2';
    $order_params['proid'] = '222'
}
```

I need to confirm if I am doing the right way, OR if there is a more better way to do this.

Comment: You'll want to define `$order_params['proid']` when you initially create the array because if you reference that index later on in your code and the if statement wasn't executed then you'll get an error.

Comment: I think the way you're doing it looks fine, but that's just like, my opinion, man.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jaco0646 No, this would get closed on Code Review for lack of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to confirm if I am doing the right way, OR if there is a more
>   better way to do this.

This is really hard to say without seeing all of your code, but you can tidy up the code a bit and approach it slightly differently by setting your values in one go:

```
$order_params = [
    'username' => 'test1',
    'password' => 'test2',
    'method' => $_SESSION['userid'] != '' ? 'Gateway2' : 'Gateway1',
    'proid' => $_SESSION['userid'] != '' ? '222' : null,
];
```

So set it in one go.

- `method` is set to "Gateway2" if you have a userid, else set to the default "Gateway1"
- `proid` is set to "222" if you have a userid, else set to the default empty (just so the array key is set and you don't later need to do `if (isset($order_params['proid']))`)

Comment: No way to tell for sure from our perspective, but it's possible that having 'proid' defined in the params is not valid for Gateway1. (If not I agree this is done more neatly.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes correct, this one is neat approach the only thing is Gateway1 do not required to send prodid , in case of Gateway1 this parameter is not required in making the API call.

Comment: It being set to empty shouldn't affect anything unless you're checking specifically `if (isset($order_params['proid']))` in which case this isn't the best approach anyway. You should (arguably) set it to null and check that. An array key not being set could be from all sorts of reasons - a file was not included, a var is wrong and so something is not being set, etc. Whereas explicitly setting it to something that means "don't do a thing" is explicit every time. eg `if ($order_params['proid'] !== null) {// then get the value that must have been set}`

Comment: If you're asking about something deeper in your approach, you'll have to show the relevant code :) I'm happy to update my answer if I can help further

Comment: thanks @James for all your help. your answer is really helpful :)